# Can i generate Dynamic Virtual hosts with Apache and Mysql

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, centos, virtualhost

I want to have a webpage where i can define my viruals hosts with all parameetrs like

```
Port
Document Root
Log
```

and all other parameters so that i can have one `Mysql Row` per `Virual hosts` and Apache gets all the `virual hosts` from there.

Is there any way of doing that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using [mod_myvhost](http://code.google.com/p/mod-myvhost/)

> mod_myvhost is Apache module for dynamically configured name based mass virtual hosting with PHP, virtual host's configurations and PHP settings are stored in database.
>
> No need to have every vhost in apache's configuration file, no need to restart apache after configuration changed (vhost added|deleted, vhost rootdir changed, vhost unblocked/unblocked...).